How to not show double quotes in ansible run output while displaying contents of a file?
clean.txt file having data without any double quotes below.
[wladmin@linuxhost ~]$ cat clean.txt
REPL session history will not be persisted.
 WDA-EMEA-PROD
{
  db: 'WDA-EMEA-PROD',
  collections: 53,
  ok: 1,
  '$clusterTime': {
    clusterTime: Timestamp({ t: 1719475282, i: 1 }),
    signature: {
      hash: Binary.createFromBase64('jXjZEjVC7wm8wCNuJVTSvGWZNO4=', 0),
      keyId: Long('7348787707444723714')
    }
  },
  operationTime: Timestamp({ t: 1719475282, i: 1 })
}
Get Collection Count

Ansible playbook trying to displaycontents of the file as is:
[wladmin@linuxhost ~]$ cat logformat.yml
---
- name: "Play 1"
  hosts: localhost

  gather_facts: no
  tasks:

    - name: Read Github logs
      raw: "cat clean.txt"
      register: file_contentone

    - debug:
        msg: "{{ file_contentone.stdout_lines }}"

Ansible playbook run showing double quotes in output.
[wladmin@linuxhost ~]$ ansible-playbook logformat.yml

PLAY [Play 1] **************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Read Github logs] ****************************************************************************************************************************************************
Thursday 27 June 2024  21:51:52 -0500 (0:00:00.013)       0:00:00.013 *********
changed: [localhost]

TASK [debug] ***************************************************************************************************************************************************************
Thursday 27 June 2024  21:51:52 -0500 (0:00:00.024)       0:00:00.038 *********
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": [
        "REPL session history will not be persisted.",
        " EMEA-PROD",
        "{",
        "  collections: 53,",
        "  ok: 1,",
        "  '$clusterTime': {",
        "    clusterTime: Timestamp({ t: 1719475282, i: 1 }),",
        "    signature: {",
        "      hash: Binary.createFromBase64('jXjZEjVC7wm8wCNuJVTSvGWZNO4=', 0),",
        "      keyId: Long('7348787707444723714')",
        "    }",
        "  },",
        "  operationTime: Timestamp({ t: 1719475282, i: 1 })",
        "}",
        "Get Collection Count"
    ]
}

PLAY RECAP *****************************************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=2    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0

Thursday 27 June 2024  21:51:52 -0500 (0:00:00.039)       0:00:00.077 *********

I understand that the file contents is without any double quotes, however Can I somehow print the output without any double quotes around each line?

This question is similar to: Formatting stdout in a debug task of Ansible and has already good answers there. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

I am going to leave aside the fact that I've seen you ask this question in at least five different shape or form already, but please do understand that Ansible's default output in debug is JSON. When you will have internalised that information, go to the next step and understand that a JSON object needs a key and a value. A typical expression would look like {"key": "value"}, so the double quote you see there is just coming from the fact that the value have to be in double quote to make it a valid JSON.

Furthermore, since you are using stdout_lines when you should probably be using stdout, your output is cut into a list (new lines of the files is transposed into a different element of a list). And a list or array in JSON is expressed in the form {"key": ["item one", "item two", "item three"]}, so, here this is why you see lots of double quotes.

But as the closure notice here says and as it said on the other similar questions you asked before there is nothing you can do about it except changing your callback plugin.

For quick reference, If Callback Plugins like posix.json – screen output as JSON or general.yaml – YAML-ized screen output do not suit the needs, one could use in example general.unixy – condensed output. As plus, the debug task would become obsolete.
